# Lineage OS on Raspberry Pi 3 with GSM Module

Tags: raspberry-pi, gsm

Im planning to create an android Raspberry Pi 3 using Lineage OS. My concern is the GSM module. Does Lineage OS can read the GSM Module (SIM900) in Raspberry Pi and detects it as a SIM Card? My goal is to send SMS using Lineage OS Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, please. If the goal (only) is to send SMS, a RPi and the GSM Module should be OK. For more, well, the RPi is not currently supported by Linage OS, as per their site.

Comment: Just making a raspberry pi sms gateway server. Im planning to use PHP and send SMS to the raspberry pi via REST API.

Answer (score 0):

### The high level view

1. connect the SIM900 module to the RPi  using the serial connection
2. write a program to send `AT` commands to the SIM900 to send SMSes
3. setup a `php` script in a web server to receive SMS parameters and make it call the program from step 2.

### Lower level view

1. You may want to read [this blog](https://elementztechblog.wordpress.com/2014/08/18/interfacing-sim900a-gsm-modem-with-raspberrypi/) to see how to connect your SOM900 to the RPi. There are actually many blogs like this one so if this one is not clear, just Google "*Connecting SIM900 Raspberry*"
2. To send SMS you need to send some so called Hayes `AT` commands to the modem. The Commands are defined in  specification "3GPP TS 27.005", but basically you need to do the following (not tested...). This is adapted Python: I don't know the equivalent of `serial` module in `php`:

   ```
   import serial
   import time

   modem=serial.Serial("/dev/<the serial device>", baudrate=9600, timeout=1.0)
   modem.open()

   modem.write("AT+CMGF=1\r")
   time.sleep(0.5)
   modem.write("AT+CMGS=\"<the desination mobile number>\"")
   modem.write(";\r")
   time.sleep(0.5)   
   modem.write(<the content of the SMS>")
   time.sleep(0.2)
   modem.write(chr(26))  # character Ctrl-Z meaning end of message
   time.sleep(0.5)
   ```

   However, if you want to send messages in a specific charset different from the *default* GSM alphabet, you'll need to need to do some coding (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38)).
3. I believe the Web Server step shouldn't be an issue for you. You need 2 parameters for your script: the destination of the message and the message itself.

Hope this helps.